# Splitting a TKInter function

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to programming in all languages and am having a crack at some python. I have a collection of the functions I've written so far which work so I can refer back to them for when I get stuck. In order to collect them together I have used tkinter to do this for me 'AddToCollection.py'. I can get it working when I run the .py file I created it in, however I would like to import it to any function I wish. Whenever I run the code with the AddToCollection imported it runs immediately. I have tried to split it into functions so that the new window will only open when I call a function but then it can't access the Entry to get the file name. Help would be appreciated. TL;DR how do I stop this code from running when it's imported?

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import messagebox as box

#pops up a box to confirm you want to save it   
def SaveConf():
    var = box.askokcancel('Save', 'Are you sure you want to save?')    
    if var == 1:
        Save(FileName.get())     



#Does the actual saving
def Save(Oldfile):
    file = open(Oldfile+".py", 'r')
    ToAdd = '\n#- '+ Oldfile +' -------------\n' + file.read() + '\n#-----------'
    file.close()
    newfile = open("/New.py", 'a+')
    newfile.write(ToAdd)
    newfile.close()
    newwind.destroy()


#setting up items in window

#Initialising window
newwind = Tk()
newwind.title('Save a file')

#to enter filename
Frame3 = Frame()
Frame3.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
FileName = Entry(Frame3)
FileName.pack(side = LEFT)

#click button
SaveBtn2 = Button(Frame3, text = 'Save to Testicles.py', command = SaveConf)
SaveBtn2.pack(side=RIGHT,padx=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to structure tkinter application is to subclass Tk and create your widget in the constructor. Here is an example of how you could architecture for your code. It pack your application in a class (subclass of `Tk`) and provide an helper function `launch_app` to initialise your class and run mainloop on it.

The point with `__name__ == "__main__"` is to segregate code executed when the script is run `#> python foo.py` from code executed when the module is imported. If you want to provide a default behavior when used as script, as well as the ability to use that functionality from another module, put it in a function and call this function from `if __name__ == "__main__"` block.

I also took the liberty to transform your code toward python coding standard (described in [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as box

#Does the actual saving
def save(oldfile):
    file_ = open(oldfile+".py", 'r')
    #[...]
    newfile.close()
    #do not destroy window here

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title('Save a file')

        frame3 = tk.Frame()
        frame3.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
        self.filename = tk.Entry(frame3)
        self.filename.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        #click button
        save_btn2 = tk.Button(frame3, text='Save to Testicles.py', command=self.save_conf)
        save_btn2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=2)

    def save_conf(self):
        var = box.askokcancel('Save', 'Are you sure you want to save?')
        if var == 1:
            save(self.FileName.get())
            self.destroy()  #<-- here come the destroy

def launch_app():
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    launch_app()
```

Comment: ahh I got it. Thank you very much. I tried to make it a class but I wasn't doing it correctly. I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you just want to import and use the functions you've written? I think part of what you're missing is this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #setting up items in window

    #Initialising window
    newwind = Tk()
    newwind.title('Save a file')

    #to enter filename
    Frame3 = Frame()
    Frame3.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
    FileName = Entry(Frame3)
    FileName.pack(side = LEFT)
```

That will prevent this code from running when the file is imported as a module.

Comment: Ahh thank you I understand, then when I want to actually use the code in 'AddToCollection', I would have to call it by something like AddToCollection(__name__ = __main__) in order for it to run?